# Alternative to WSGIDaemonProcess & WSGIProcessGroup for Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I have installed the following on my **Windows** machine (everything is 64bit):

- Python 3.4.3
- [Apache 2.4.16](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC10/)
- [mod_wsgi 4.4.13](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi)

Then I installed Django(v1.8.3) in a virtual environment using virtualenv. Using `django-admin` I created ***two*** project and I created ***two*** `VirtualHost` for that. And everything is working perfect. Now I would like to use a ***different environment*** for the second project but though the Windows doesn't support `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIProcessGroup` I don't know how to do that.

```
WSGIPythonPath "C:/_pythonDev/project1;C:/_pythonDev/project2;C:/_pythonDev/env1/Lib/site-packages"
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName one.local.com

  WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/_pythonDev/project1/project1/wsgi.py"

  <Directory "C:/_pythonDev/project1/project1">
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName two.local.com

  WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/_pythonDev/project2/project2/wsgi.py"

  <Directory "C:/_pythonDev/project2/project2">
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, If someone knows how to run Django projects in different environment please guide me.

**Solution:** [click this link](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s226/sh/0bc9542c-f743-4f83-ab14-e2d8700baf8c/3bbf2e3019689f14830fdbb3a618e6f4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to address two things.

1. Don't set WSGIPythonPath in the Apache configuration. Activate the Python virtual environment and set sys.path from the WSGI script file.
2. Change the WSGI script file so as not to use setdefault() in os.environ as that screws things up.

For reading see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html

Comment: Its working now. I removed `WSGIPythonPath` from `.conf` file and activated the environment using `env\\Scripts\\activate_this.py` in `wsgi.py` itself.

Comment: loading time is unstable sometimes it takes 10s even after using `WSGIImportScript`. Can you help me solve that too?

Comment: Rather than use WSGIImportScript, you can supply process-group and application-group options to WSGIScriptAlias and if both exist, it will preload the script. Whether that will work on Windows, where you can only supply application-group to WSGIScriptAlias I can't remember. Anyway, for any new question about loading time, create a new question in SO. Explain what you are doing in your WSGI script file. For example, is data being preloaded from a database.